# How do I format a field code in Microsoft (MS) Word 2007 using VB?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am trying to insert a field code that references a bookmark in the middle of a sentence in MS word 2007.  I would like the field code to be bold and italicized but have not been successful in formatting the field code using vb.

Here's what I have which seems like it should work but it does not.

```
Private WithEvents wordApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application
Private doc As Word.Document = wordApp.Documents.Add()
Dim bmRange As Word.Range = Nothing
Dim s As Word.Selection = wordApp.Selection

With s
  .Style = "Normal"
  .TypeText("THIS IS THE COURSE TITLE")
  .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
  .StartOf(Word.WdUnits.wdSentence, Word.WdMovementType.wdExtend)
  bmRange = .Range
  .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
  .TypeParagraph()
  .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
End With

doc.Bookmarks.Add("CourseTitle", bmRange)
```

Now the bookmark is set at the top of the document.  Let's say we are a couple pages into the doc now.

```
s = wordApp.Selection
With s
   .Style = "Normal"
   .TypeText("This is the first part of the sentence ")
   With .Range
     .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
     .Fields.Add(s.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, "REF CourseTitle", True)
     .Font.Bold = -1
     .Font.Italic = -1
     .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
     .Font.Bold = 0
     .Font.Italic = 0
   End With
   .TypeText(" this is the rest of the sentence.")
End With
```

This will place the field code where I want it but it does not format it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your second chunk of code, the following will probably do what you want:

```
Dim f as Word.Field
s = wordApp.Selection
With s
   .Style = "Normal"
   .TypeText("This is the first part of the sentence ")
   With .Range
     .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
     f = .Fields.Add(s.Range, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldEmpty, "REF CourseTitle", True)
     f.Result.Bold = -1
     f.Result.Italic = -1
     .Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
   End With
   .TypeText(" this is the rest of the sentence.")
End With
```

There are other things I would probably change in the code, e.g. get a Range object from the Selection earlier in the code and work with that in preference to the Selection object. (Not essential, but a good practice in Word).